# how to upload a .url file

Tags: windows-10, hyperlink

I've created a .URL file in Windows 10 by dragging a shortcut onto the desktop and I can see it's just a plain text file with a .url extension.

However, if I try to upload it into a web site that uses a standard HTML file upload control, I can see that what it actually tries to upload seems to be the HTML of the web page but with a random filename, no file extension, and incorrect content-type header. It's the same in all the browsers I've seen so I guess Windows is responsible for this behaviour.

Just to be clear, I'm not asking for anything clever to happen here; I just want my ".url" file to be uploaded onto the web server and treated like any other file extension would be.

Comment: What if you rename the file to .txt, upload it then, then rename on the serverside?

Comment: @LPChip that would be possible but I'm trying to come up with something that doesn't require user training or server-side enhancements.

Comment: Isn't an .url file just a text file with the url inside? I'd use the url instead and paste it into a webform as plain text to manage it like that rather than using an upload form. You could script it to create the .url file serverside based on the url entered in the form.

Comment: That's not necessarily Windows's fault, it could just as well be the browsers anonymizing the file.

Comment: @LPChip yes, but I'm using an existing application that I can't change

Comment: So technically, you're abusing .url files, which doesn't work, and now you blame the web. What you want just cannot be done.

Comment: You're not supposed to upload .url files.

Comment: when you say "abuse" and "supposed to" I presume you have access to some documentation that explains what is permissible with these files. If you could share it, this would be of great interest to me.